# The class 'Sonata\PageBundle\Model\Site' was not found in the chain configured namespaces

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

I am working on a `Symfony 3.3` application that uses Sonata's page bundle.

I want to create a Page fixture that is assigned to a Site. To get the repository of available sites, I have attempted to use this line of code:

```
$siteRepository = $manager->getRepository('Sonata\PageBundle\Model\Site');
```

... But I get the following error:

> The class 'Sonata\PageBundle\Model\Site' was not found in the chain
>   configured namespaces Application\Sonata\Clas
>   sificationBundle\Entity, Sonata\ClassificationBundle\Entity,
>   Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity, Sonata\MediaB   undle\Entity,
>   Sonata\NotificationBundle\Entity,
>   Application\Sonata\NotificationBundle\Entity, Application\Sonata\
>   PageBundle\Entity, Sonata\PageBundle\Entity, Sonata\UserBundle\Entity,
>   Spy\TimelineBundle\Entity, Application\Son
>   ata\TimelineBundle\Entity, Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity,
>   Sonata\TimelineBundle\Entity, AppBundle\Entity

**What am I doing wrong here?**

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that this class was already being extended locally, so I was able to get something that worked by using:

```
$siteRepository = $manager->getRepository('ApplicationSonataPageBundle:Site');
```

That doesn't really answer my original question, but maybe it will help somebody.